# Creating a hierarchical dictionary with nested lists or dictionaries from 2 lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have 2 lists. The first has number denoting what part of the hierarchy that the value in the other list at the same index belongs. I am trying to get dynamic code that could theoretically go to any number of steps.

The first 3 work correctly but when I had more steps to the hierarchy I cant get a perfect return. I am just learning Python so if there are any suggestions to improve my ugly code as well I would appreciate it.

The first list is a list containing numbers. These numbers are the step within the hierarchy. The second list will be sorted based off the step value of the first list at their shared indexes.

below are 3 examples of what I am trying. The first 2 are correct but they only work for steps 0 and 1. I am trying to make the code to where it will work with any length of lists and any number range (the next steps can only be +/- 1).

output should look like this, using the first list showing the steps:

```
0
0
 1
 1
  2
   3
  2
  2
 1
0
 1
  2
   3
   3
```

I would like to set all 0 steps set to a dictionary of the value of the same index of the second list. This dictionary will contain either a nested list or nested dictionaries. I am not sure which is the better way to go for this.

I apologize for any confusion and thank you for any help.

```
#!/bin/usr/env python

from pprint import pprint

print('\n')

list1 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
lista = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e']
dict = {}
for index, value in enumerate(lista):
  inc = 1
  if (list1[index] == 0):
     dict[value] = []
     try:
        while (list1[index + inc] > 0):
            dict[value].append(lista[index + inc])
            inc += 1
     except IndexError:
        pass

pprint(dict)

print('\n' + '#'*150 + "\n")

list2 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
listb = ['a','b','c','d','e', 'f', 'g']
dict = {}
for index, value in enumerate(listb):
   inc = 1
    if (list2[index] == 0):
        dict[value] = []
        try:
            while (list2[index + inc] > 0):
                dict[value].append(listb[index + inc])
                inc += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass

pprint(dict)

print('\n' + '#'*150 + "\n")

list3 = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
listc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ,'f' , 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm' ,'n' ,'o' , 'p', 'q' ,'r' ,'s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']

dict = {}
temp_dict = {}
for index, value in enumerate(listc):
    inc = 1
    if (list3[index] == 0):
       dict[value] = []
        try:
            while (list3[index + inc] > 0):
                if (list3[index + inc] < list3[index + (inc + 1)]):
                    dict[value].append([listc[index + inc]])
                elif (list3[index + inc] == list3[index + (inc + 1)]):
                    dict[value].append()
                inc += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass

pprint(dict)

print('\n' + '#'*150 + "\n")
```

This is the current output.

```
{'a': ['b'], 'c': ['d', 'e']}

######################################################################################################################################################

{'a': ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'f': ['g']}

######################################################################################################################################################

{'a': [['b']], 'v': [['w']]}

######################################################################################################################################################
```

I am trying to get the third output to look like this.

```
{
'a': [ 'b', 
          [ 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u'], 
'v': [ 'w', 
          [ 'x']] 
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from the description what you eventually want to get. Could you include one or two examples of input and its corresponding expected output?

Comment: I think something you need to add in this append.. `dict[value].append()`

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I added some things to the bottom to help clarify. Thank you

Comment: Can the numbers list go back, but not to zero? That is, can you have [0, 1, 2, 1, 2]? If so, what would it mean?

Comment: Also, what's the required output for list1 and list-a?

Comment: The numbers can go back to 0. All zero values in list1 should use the index of lista as a dictionary key containing all the steps until the next 0 value in list1.

Comment: what's the required output for [0, 0, 0] and [a, b, c] ? Or is that not a valid case?

Comment: And a similar question - what's the required output for [0, 1, 0, 0] and [a, b, c, d]? Again - is that a valid input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. Note, that in addition to the actual result is returns how many items were consumed from the list. You can of course ignore that if you'd like.

```
def build_dict_from_lists(depth_list, item_list):
    if len(depth_list) != len(item_list):
        raise Exception("Canincompatible lengths")

    depth0 = depth_list[0]

    res = []
    next_index = 0
    while next_index < len(depth_list) and  depth_list[next_index] >= depth0:
        item = item_list[next_index]
        depth = depth_list[next_index]        
        if depth == depth0:
            res.append(item)
            next_index += 1
        else: 
            consumed, sub_res = build_dict_from_lists(depth_list[next_index:], item_list[next_index:])
            res.append(sub_res) 
            next_index += consumed 

    if depth0 == 0 and any(isinstance(x, list) for x in res): # switch the result from a dict to a list
        d = {}
        for inx in range(0, len(res), 2):
            key = res[inx]
            val = res[inx + 1]
            d[key] = val
        res = d 

    return next_index, res
```

A few tests to verify the correctness of the code:

```
assert build_dict_from_lists([0, 0, 0], ["a", "b", "c"]) == (3, ['a', 'b', 'c'])

assert build_dict_from_lists([0, 1, 2], ["a", "b", "c"]) == (3, {'a': ['b', ['c']]})
assert build_dict_from_lists([0, 1, 2, 1, 2], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]) == (5, {'a': ['b', ['c'], 'd', ['e']]})

list3 = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
listc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ,'f' , 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm' ,'n' ,'o' , 'p', 'q' ,'r' ,'s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']

expected = {'a': 
[ 'b', 
          [ 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u']], 
'v': [ 'w', 
          [ 'x']] 
}
assert build_dict_from_lists(list3, listc) == (24, expected)

list4 = [0, 1, 1,     2,   2, 2,   2, 1,  2, 1, ] 
listd = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'] 
assert build_dict_from_lists(list4, listd) == (10, {'a': ['b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'h', ['i'], 'j']})

list5 = [0,   1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3] 
liste = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'] 
assert build_dict_from_lists(list5, liste) == (12, {'a': ['b', 'c', ['d', 'e', ['f', 'g']], 'h', 'i', ['j', 'k', ['l']]]})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have learned a bunch from your code like assert and zip. One thing that I am confused about is that you are calling your method within your method (line 18). I like how you are using the consumed variable. This code does work and I like it however it doesn't work for other list pairs than the ones in my code. 

eg)
`
list4 = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
listd = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

list5 = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
liste = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']
`

Comment: Yep. I see my error. My mistake was that I thought you're build a dictionary of N levels deep. I then saw that just the top level is a dict. The deeper levels are all lists. Is that on purpose?

Comment: See my improved solution. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That looks great. It will take me a bit to go through your code and understand everything. I choose a dictionary of lists because... I don't know. I am new to python and thought it would be easier i guess. A dictionary of a list of dictionaries would probably be the better route though. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would probably go for a hierarchical list. No dictionaries at all. That would simplify things a bit.

Comment: Did this answer your question?